# how to develop socket like approach with aws lambda (serverless architecture)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

How to develop/refactor a node.js project that uses socket.io and send JSON data from a client to another in a room?

I've developed a project with node js and socket.io that there is a board game in a part of it, the user1 select a place and its information send to the user2 in JSON format and this part developed with socket.io.

now I want to deploy the project to AWS Lambda but I realize that socket.io can't run because of serverless nature, so my question is how can I develop this board game with AWS Lambda and what technology/library can I use?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do socket.io like bi-directional communication only using AWS Lambda since it is stateless and asynchronous. You can use [AWS IOT Web Sockets](https://medium.com/@jparreira/receiving-aws-iot-messages-in-your-browser-using-websockets-9b87f28c2357) for this(Optionally with Lambda).